# Removendo o objeto Dictionary com condição - Firebase - Swift

Tags: ios, firebase, swift, xcode

No meu App eu preciso listar informações cadastradas pelo usuário, existe um campo "enable" onde "on" não será exibido no tableViewController, se "yes" vai listar, código abaixo para ajuda. Primeiro item não deve ser exibido. Obrigado.

[image: Imagem da tableViewController]

```
    let snapshot = self.listaDadosCombustivel[indexPath.row]
    let key = snapshot.key 

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "celulaDados", for: indexPath) as! CadastroDadosCell



    let snapshot = self.listaDadosCombustivel[indexPath.row]
    let key = snapshot.key
    let snapshotAnterior = self.listaDadosCombustivel[indexPath.row.littleEndian]
    self.idCadCombustivelAnterior = snapshotAnterior.key

    if var dados = snapshot.value as? [String : Any]{
        if let enable = dados["enable"] as? String{
            if enable == "yes"{
                if let dataAbastecimento = dados["dataAbastecimento"] as? String{
                    if let valorTotal = dados["valorTotal"] as? String{
                        if let litrosTotal = dados["litroTotal"] as? String{
                            if let kmAtual = dados["kmAtual"] as? String{
                                if let combustivel = dados["combustivel"] as? String{
                                    if let consumo = dados["consumo"] as? String{
                                        cell.dataLabel.text = dataAbastecimento
                                        cell.valorTotalLabel.text = valorTotal
                                        cell.litrosTotalLabel.text = litrosTotal
                                        cell.combustivelLabel.text = combustivel
                                        cell.kmVeiculoLabel.text = kmAtual
                                        cell.kmLitroLabel.text = consumo
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }else{
                print(key)
            }
        }            
    }
    return cell
}
```

Comment: seria interessante você pesquisa sobre Codable, para fazer um Parser dessa estrutura (listaDadosCombustivel).

Answer (score 2):

Tenta isso.

```swift
struct Combustivel: Codable {

    var enable: String?
    var dataAbastecimento: String?
    var valorTotal: String?
    var litroTotal: String?
    var kmAtual: String?
    var combustivel: String?
    var consumo: String?

}

class CadastroDadosCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var dataLabel: UILabel?
    @IBOutlet weak var valorTotalLabel: UILabel?
    @IBOutlet weak var litrosTotalLabel: UILabel?
    @IBOutlet weak var combustivelLabel: UILabel?
    @IBOutlet weak var kmVeiculoLabel: UILabel?
    @IBOutlet weak var kmLitroLabel: UILabel?
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

 @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var combList: [Combustivel] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // ...
       guard let data = data else { return }

            do {
                let combustivels = try JSONDecoder().decode([Combustivel].self, from: data)

                if combustivels != nil{
                   self.combList = combustivels
               }else {
                   print("nothing to display")
               }

               DispatchQueue.main.async {
                  self.tableView.reloadData()
               }
             } catch let jsonErr {
            print("Error serializing json:", jsonErr)
        }
    }
//...
}
extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return combList.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "celulaDados", for: indexPath) as! CadastroDadosCell

    let item = self.dataSource[indexPath.row]

    if item.enable == "yes" {
        cell.dataLabel?.text = item.dataAbastecimento
        cell.valorTotalLabel?.text = item.valorTotal
        cell.litrosTotalLabel?.text = item.litroTotal
        cell.combustivelLabel?.text = item.combustivel
        cell.kmVeiculoLabel?.text = item.kmAtual
        cell.kmLitroLabel?.text = item.consumo
    }
    return cell
}
}
```

Comment: `if combustivels != nil{` ? decode would return a non optional object, in case it fails it would just throw it doesn't return nil. If you would like to return an optional you would need to remove the do catch and change it to `try?` to ignore the error and return nil in case of failure